# Each instance of the model has one or more instances of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to indicate that each instance of the model has **one** or more instances of another model.

I always see how to indicate one-to-many (each instance of the model has **zero** or more instances of another model) with the `has_many` - `belongs_to`

Typically

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items 

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
```

But for a relationship Order ----> **1**..n LineItem ????

Comment: Sounds like you just need a validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On LineItem, add `validates_presence_of :cart_id`

On Cart, add `inverse_of :cart` to the has_many declaration

Official Rails solution:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence

Comment: FYI, validating `cart_id` does not guarantee presence. For that you have to use `validates :cart, presence: true` only. Also, it's recommended you use the new validation syntax: `validates :cart_id, presence: true`

Comment: Both ways pass the attribute to `ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator` so it doesn't matter what you use.  Using `validates` is recommended if you are running multiple validations against the attribute.

Comment: No, they are not the same. Checking for presence of cart_id simply validates that there is an integer, and the column is not blank. The cart can be deleted, or may not exist, and LineItem would still be valid. Checking for presence of object **queries the database** to see if the object does exist, if it doesn't LineItem will not be valid. http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/

Answer (score 1):

You would still use `has_many` and `belongs_to`. But you have to be sure that an instance of the parent can not exist without any instances of the child, and vice-versa. You can do this in several ways. From the child side:

1. Create the parent object first. Only create child instances if there is a parent to assign to
2. Create both objects at the same time using nested forms
3. Use validations to ensure that the child has a parent before saving it

Or from the parent side:

1. Create an Order only if there are LineItem to assign to it
2. Create the Order but do not alter its state until you have added LineItems
3. Create both at the same time using nested forms

There are a few more scenarios, but this illustrates the point. It really depends on how you model your objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :line_items
    validates_presence_of :line_item_id
end
```

I think this is what you want. The cart should have 1...n Line Items.